# Stackoverflow Tray Application

Tags: support, stack-overflow, stackapps

Hi folks!

**Question:** I wonder, if there exists any `small tray application`, which could show my runtime SO statistics, incoming comments or changes in favorites and other stuff, taken from stack?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

[StackTray: The Stack Overflow tray application](https://stackapps.com/questions/117/stacktray-the-stackoverflow-tray-application)

Comment: @JLWarlow Not the windows version... but still thanks! Any answers? :)